# Angular huge stacktrace

Tags: angular

I get exception stack trace in chrome console which is 283 lines, the lines referring to my code are 80 - 81 (search for word Card).

```
  at CardService.getCards (eval at 70
 (http://localhost:8080/app.js:142:1), <anonymous>:46:14)
     at CardsComponent.ngOnInit (eval at 144 (http://localhost:8080/app.js:7:1), <anonymous>:19:26)
```

I wonder why all the junk is getting into exception and is there a way to get rid of it?

Stacktrace (reduced a little)

```
 (unknown) ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status:
 401 Unauthorized for URL: http://localhost:5000/api/user
     at resolvePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:783:31)
     at resolvePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:754:17)
     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:831:17)
     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:424:31)
     at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:4085:33)
     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:423:36)
     at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:191:47)
     at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:595:35)
     at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:502:21)
     at invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:1364:14)
     at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:1382:17)
     at ____________________Elapsed_13_ms__At__Thu_Jul_27_2017_14_51_10_GMT_0300__Turkey_Standard_Time_
 (http://localhost)
     at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2706:1), <anonymous>:109:22)
     at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:404:51)
     at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:300:29)
     at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:404:51)
     at Zone.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:235:43)
     at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:255:25)
     at scheduleResolveOrReject (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:829:14)
     at resolvePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:778:21)
     at resolvePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:754:17)
     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:831:17)
     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:424:31)
     at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:4085:33)
     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:423:36)
     at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:191:47)
     at drainMicroTaskQueue (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:595:35)
     at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:502:21)
     at invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:1364:14)
     at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:1382:17)
     at ____________________Elapsed_1_ms__At__Thu_Jul_27_2017_14_51_10_GMT_0300__Turkey_Standard_Time_
 (http://localhost)
     at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2706:1), <anonymous>:109:22)
     at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:404:51)
     at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:300:29)
     at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:404:51)
     at Zone.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:235:43)
     at Zone.scheduleMicroTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:255:25)
     at scheduleResolveOrReject (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:829:14)
     at resolvePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:778:21)
     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:709:17)
     at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _error] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2626:1), <anonymous>:68:85)
     at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:14:1), <anonymous>:238:16)
     at SafeSubscriber.error (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:14:1), <anonymous>:197:26)
     at Subscriber._error (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:14:1), <anonymous>:128:26)
     at Subscriber.error (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:14:1), <anonymous>:102:18)
     at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:336:1), <anonymous>:1270:34)
     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:424:31)
     at Object.onInvokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:4085:33)
     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:423:36)
     at Zone.runTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:191:47)
     at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:498:34)
     at invokeTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:1364:14)
     at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:1382:17)
     at ____________________Elapsed_94_ms__At__Thu_Jul_27_2017_14_51_10_GMT_0300__Turkey_Standard_Time_
 (http://localhost)
     at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2706:1), <anonymous>:109:22)
     at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:404:51)
     at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:300:29)
     at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:404:51)
     at Zone.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:235:43)
     at Zone.scheduleEventTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:261:25)
     at XMLHttpRequest.eval [as addEventListener] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:1634:33)
     at XMLHttpRequest.__zone_symbol__send (<anonymous>:1:682)
     at ZoneTask.scheduleTask [as scheduleFn] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:2616:24)
     at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:410:26)
     at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2706:1), <anonymous>:117:35)
     at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:404:51)
     at Object.onScheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:300:29)
     at ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:404:51)
     at Zone.scheduleTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:235:43)
     at Zone.scheduleMacroTask (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:258:25)
     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:2640:29)
     at XMLHttpRequest.proto.(anonymous function) [as send] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1),
 <anonymous>:1221:20)
     at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:336:1), <anonymous>:1314:18)
     at Observable._trySubscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6:1), <anonymous>:171:25)
     at Observable.subscribe (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:6:1), <anonymous>:159:65)
     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2626:1), <anonymous>:68:15)
     at new ZoneAwarePromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/polyfills.js:2712:1), <anonymous>:847:29)
     at Observable.toPromise (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:2626:1), <anonymous>:66:12)
     at CardService.getCards (eval at 70 (http://localhost:8080/app.js:142:1), <anonymous>:46:14)
     at CardsComponent.ngOnInit (eval at 144 (http://localhost:8080/app.js:7:1), <anonymous>:19:26)
     at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:11038:19)
     at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:12534:17)
     at checkAndUpdateNode (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:12473:16)
     at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:13334:59)
     at debugCheckDirectivesFn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:13275:13)
     at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///AppModule/CardsComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:8:5)
     at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1),
 <anonymous>:13260:21)
     at checkAndUpdateView (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:12440:14)
     at callViewAction (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:12805:21)
     at execEmbeddedViewsAction (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:12763:17)
     at checkAndUpdateView (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:12441:5)
     at callViewAction (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:12805:21)
     at execComponentViewsAction (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:12737:13)
     at checkAndUpdateView (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:12446:5)
     at callWithDebugContext (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:13660:42)
     at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1),
 <anonymous>:13200:12)
     at ViewRef_.detectChanges (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:10371:18)
     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:67:1), <anonymous>:5009:63)
     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Why do you care exactly?

Comment: @Igor - this is not a big problem, but still pretty annoying. Why do I have to scroll multiple screens searching for the source of problem? In the end of the day it adds up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first 2 lines are also relevant i'd suppose?

`(unknown) ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status:
 401 Unauthorized for URL: http://localhost:5000/api/user`

Isn't it that request that makes your `ngOnInit` to fail?

Comment: Correct, it helps to find source of the problem but it is too general. I would like to see where exactly in my code problem happens. For some reason this information is in the middle of 283 lines.]

Comment: if you handle the error in your api with a `catch(function(error) {console.log(error)});` im pretty sure you will find out the error more specific? angular always have these weird and general stack traces..

Comment: Thanks Lucas, I can handle this particular case. Wanted to know if there a way to make angular stack traces more to the point in the future. Oh well..

Comment: oh okay, no, they will always suck and you will always have to use some what of dark magic to understand when you've done wrong :)